# Getting GoogleMaps For Mobile to follow a predefined route

Tags: android, jquery, ios, google-maps, navigator

I´ve been searching around for a way to use androids(and iOS) native navigator to follow a predefined polyline and navigating the user according to it. I´ve seen alot of people requesting this service, but the latest posts are from around 2012. Is this possible?

It would be easiest just to send the start and end point of the route, togheter with a few waypoints to the navigator, but I cant find a way to do it. I´ve been experimenting alot with it and the last week I even tried to divide the route into sections, and navigate one at a time. This isnt a viable solution though, since the users of my application wont accept to stop four-five times through a route to restart the navigation..

Any help is appreciated, I´ve ripped all the hair from my head as of now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have got in mind

create a list that contains the return JSON of directions.
put each start and end latlng step into the list.

while your marker is moving every so often, check if the current marker is outside the line of the current step.

Here is also a post I made sometime ago

[Google direction and voice navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290517/google-direction-and-voice-navigation)

hope it helps